# How to get an object from a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to get the speed of a Test object from a HashMap when given the key but I'm not quite sure how to do it. I tried this way but its wrong:

```
hash.values().getSpeed();
```

Any help? Thanks

```
class Test {

            private String id;
            private String name;
            private int speed;

            public Test(String id, String name, int speed) {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.speed = speed;

            }

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;

            }

            public int getSpeed() {
                return speed;
            }
        }    
    public class Driver {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Test> hash = new HashMap<String, Test>();

            Test c1;
            Test c2;

            c1 = new Test("Z", "B", 4);
            c2 = new Test("Y", "D", 7);
            hash.put("A", c1);
            hash.put("C", c2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Test c1;
Test c2;

c1 = new Test("Z", "B", 4);
c2 = new Test("Y", "D", 7);
hash.put("A", c1);
hash.put("C", c2);

Test getC1 = (Test)hash.get("A");
Test getC2 = (Test)hash.get("C");
```

Comment: Thanks Mi Mee, that code wasn't exactly what I wanted but it helped me solve the problem. I was trying to do this: hash.get("C").getSpeed();

Comment: @Mi Mee - No need to cast the value. You can use Test t=hash.get("A");

Comment: Yes, you're right, since HashMap was initialized with <String, Test>. Just realized it now.

Answer (score 3):

The [values()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) method returns a collection of *values* contained in the `HashMap` object. You may use `for loop` to traverse the values collection.

```
for(Test t:hash.values())
{
  System.out.println(t.getSpeed());
}
```

Comment: Thanks AVD. I was trying to only get the speed of a specific key but this might be useful later on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method in the Map interface with the following signature + return type I think:

```
E get(T key);
```

Answer (score 1):

`hash.get("A")`, or more generally: `hash.get(key)`, where `key` was the first argument to a `hash.put(key, value)` call.

Answer (score 0):

`get` is the inverse of `put`. So just `hash.get("C");` will give you `c1`, etc.

I suggest you look over Javadoc of the classes you use more thoroughly before posting.

Comment: Im trying to get the speed of c1, not just the object c1

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Driver {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Test> hash = new HashMap<String, Test>();
        Test c1;
        Test c2;
        c1 = new Test("A", "Maruthi", 4);
        c2 = new Test("B", "Toyota", 7);
        hash.put("A", c1);
        hash.put("B", c2);
        for(Test t:hash.values()) {
          System.out.println(t.getSpeed() + " " + t.getId() + " " + t.getName());
        }
    }
}
```