# Serialize multiple different objects single in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I might be trying to do this the hard way so let me know if there is a better solution.

I am making a simple text game in Java which you select your actions by a GUI. I have a couple of classes I am trying to serialize one being the player and another being an NPC. Is there an easy way to serialize more then one object (player and NPC) into the same file? I can serialize one object and load it back into the game.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a simpler way of trying to save the game state?

If I have a class that creates multiple objects and I serialize that class, will the objects it created be serialized as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate approach to writing objects sequentially is to store them in a collection (e.g. a HashMap), since collections can be serialized.  This may make it a little easier to manage upon retrieval, especially if you have many objects to serialize/deserialize.  The following code demonstrates this:

```
    String first = "first";
    String second = "second";
    HashMap<String, Object> saved = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    saved.put("A", first);
    saved.put("B", second);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.obj");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(saved);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fos.close();


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.obj");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        HashMap<String,Object> retreived = (HashMap<String,Object>)ois.readObject();
        fis.close();

        System.out.println(retreived.get("A"));
        System.out.println(retreived.get("B"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Running this should result in:

```
first
second
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it has worked. Instead of just printing out "A" and "B" into the console how as assign it back to an object I can do things with?

Comment: I figured it out from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857935/how-to-get-an-object-from-a-hashmap-in-java

Thanks again for your answer it put me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `writeObject()` as many times with as many different objects as you need, and conversely call `readObject()` ditto.

Hard to believe you haven't already tried it.